# org-mode babel python session and inlined image incompatible?

Tags: org-mode

If I use this block

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results file
from pylab import *
plot(rand(10))
savefig('images/test.png')
return 'images/test.png'
#+END_SRC
```

then the RESULTS block shows me an inlined version of the plot.

If now I switch to this block

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :session test :results file
from pylab import *
plot(rand(10))
savefig('images/test.png')
return 'images/test.png'
#+END_SRC
```

then the RESULTS block does not show the inlined plot but this

```
| <matplotlib.lines.Line2D | object | at | 0x35c0650> |
```

Using a session is kind of mandatory for me because I need several blocks to share variables.

Is there something evidently wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 2):

As per the [org-mode documentation](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Results-of-evaluation), you have to drop the `return` if the code is running in a session.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :session test :results file
  from pylab import *
  plot(rand(10))
  savefig('images/test.png')
  'images/test.png'
#+END_SRC 

#+RESULTS:
[[file:images/test.png]]
```

because "the result returned is the result of the last evaluation performed by the interpreter."